# why is process.chdir() changing drive?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS with Node v5.3.0

```
$ node
> process.chdir('/source'); console.log(process.cwd());
/mnt/source
```

As you can see in this example, chdir should change my cwd to /source, but instead it changes it to /mnt/source. Can anyone provide any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: Because /source is a symlink to /mnt/source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sami-kuhmonen was correct. /source was a symlink.

```
$ ls -la /source
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 11 17:07 /source -> /mnt/source/
```